# Regex: how do I not replace numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function:

```
export const formatScenarioName = (name) => (
  name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()
)
```

I believe this removes (white)spaces and special characters, and replaces spaces with hyphens. However it's replacing numbers as well. How do I do the opposite of that? I'd want to keep the numbers.

Comment: Add `0-9` to the first regex character group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
export const formatScenarioName = (name) => (
    name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()
)
```

but you could also use `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9` you end up with

`/[^\w ]/g`

However it includes the `_` character https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: there is no need for return statement in expression arrow function

Comment: There is also no need for brackets around either the argument or function body, so `name => name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()`. If you do *toLowerCase* first then `A-Z` is redundant too. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! though I tried `\w`, not having the `_` character was a requirement. However, the former works.

Answer (score -1):

In one line:

```
const formatScenarioName = name => name.replace(/\W/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()
```

Example:

```js
const formatScenarioName = name => name.replace(/\W/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()

var test = 'test0 . 23430v 34'

console.log(formatScenarioName(test))
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question... yes it now keeps numeric characters, but it also hasn't removed _any_ special characters in case you didn't notice.

Comment: `/w/` should perhaps be `/\W/`?